# Django Form refreshes without changes! No Error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

So I have a Folder model, and 2 other models that are related to it via a ForeignKey. I have this method for creating 3 separate objects using 3 forms (creating the **Folder** object, and uploading files to 2 separate models that are related to **Folder**):

```
@login_required
def nouveaudossier(request):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
            dossier_form.created_by = Prestataire.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            dossier_form.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()
            messages.success(request,
                             "Dossier créé!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    else:
        dossierForm = DossierForm()
        formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'dashboard/nouveau_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2})
```

The view is working great, here is the screenshot of it: [image]

Now I want to make an **Edit** form, to take the id of the model in question, and populates the form and let the user, of course, make the necessary changes. Here is what I did:

```
@login_required
def reviserdossier(request, pk):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        instance_dossier = Dossier.objects.get(pk=pk)
        dossierForm = DossierForm(instance=instance_dossier)
        instance_document = DocumentdeBase.objects.get(pk=pk)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(instance=instance_document)
        instance_photo = PhotoAvant.objects.get(pk=pk)
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(instance=instance_photo)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
            dossier_form.created_by = Prestataire.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            dossier_form.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()
            messages.success(request, "Dossier mis à jour!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/reviser_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2})
```

When I run this, I get this error: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'`

This is what I found in many tutorials, to use the instance keyword. Am I missing something here?
Thank you!

Here is my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/dossiers/reviser/7

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'photologue']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\verautov0\verautonoapi\dashboard\views.py" in reviserdossier
  777.         formset = DocumentFormSet(instance=instance_document)

File "C:\Users\Kaiss Bouali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __init__
  569.         super().__init__(**{'data': data, 'files': files, 'auto_id': auto_id, 'prefix': prefix, **kwargs})

Exception Type: TypeError at /dossiers/reviser/7
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

**forms.py:**

```
class DossierForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mat_id = forms.CharField(max_length=7, label="N°")
    mattypes = (
        ('A - أ', 'A - أ'),
        ('B - ب', 'B - ب'),
        ('D - د', 'D - د'),
        ('H - ه', 'H - ه'),
        ('O - و', 'O - و'),
        ('M - المغرب', 'M - المغرب'),
        ('P - ش', 'P - ش'),
        ('J - ج', 'J - ج'),
        ('FAR - ق م م', 'FAR - ق م م'),
        ('FA - ق س', 'FA - ق س'),
        ('PC - و م', 'PC - و م'),
        ('CD - ه د', 'CD - ه د'),
        ('CI - ت د', 'CI - ت د'),
        ('CC - ت د', 'CC - ت د'),
        ('WW', 'WW'),
        ('W18', 'W18'),
        ('96', '96'),
        ('97', '97'),
        ('98', '98'),
        ('99', '99'),
    )
    mat_symbol = forms.CharField(label='Symbole', widget=forms.Select(choices=mattypes))
    mat_ville = forms.CharField(max_length=2, label='Ville')
    assurance = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Assurance.objects.all())
    ville = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())
    intermediaire = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Intermediaire.objects.all())
    marque = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Marque.objects.all())
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all())
    client_name = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    num_police = forms.IntegerField()
    glace_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=GlassType.objects.all())
    glace = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Glass.objects.all())
    joint = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)
    OV = ( # Options Vitre
        ('AD', 'AD'),
        ('SD', 'SD'),
        ('T', 'T'),
        ('ST', 'ST'),
    )

    option_vitre = forms.CharField(label='Option vitre', widget=forms.Select(choices=OV))
    valeur_assuree = forms.IntegerField(label='Valeur assurée')
    num_sinistre = forms.IntegerField(label='N° sinistre')
    date_sinistre = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=MONTHS), label='Date sinistre')
    date_effet = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=MONTHS), label='Date effet')
    date_echeance = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=MONTHS), label='Date échéance')
    franchise_contractuelle = forms.IntegerField(label='Franchise contractuelle')
    franchise_a_recuperer = forms.IntegerField(label='Franchise à récupérer')
    tva_a_recuperer = forms.IntegerField(label='TVA à récupérer')
    commentaire = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Commentaire')
    rejection_count = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Dossier
        fields = ('mat_id', 'mat_symbol', 'mat_ville', 'assurance', 'ville',
        'intermediaire', 'marque', 'model', 'client_name', 'num_police',
        'glace_type', 'glace', 'joint', 'option_vitre', 'valeur_assuree',
        'num_sinistre', 'date_sinistre', 'date_effet', 'date_echeance',
        'franchise_contractuelle', 'franchise_a_recuperer', 'tva_a_recuperer',
        'commentaire', 'rejection_count')

class DocumentdebaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    documentdebase_image = forms.ImageField(label='')

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentdeBase
        fields = ('documentdebase_image',)

class PhotoAvantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photoavant_image = forms.ImageField(label='')

    class Meta:
        model = PhotoAvant
        fields = ('photoavant_image',)
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the updated view:

```
@login_required
def reviserdossier(request, pk):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)
    instance_dossier = Dossier.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            if instance_dossier.rejection_count == 1:
                dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
                dossier_form.status_admin = 'Validation OR Requise'
                dossier_form.status_prestataire = "En Attente d'ordre de réparation"
                dossier_form.rejection_count = 0
                dossier_form.save()
            elif instance_dossier.rejection_count == 2:
                dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
                dossier_form.status_admin = 'Dossier à clôturer'
                dossier_form.status_prestataire = "En attente de clôture"
                dossier_form.rejection_count = 0
                dossier_form.save()

            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    else:
        dossierForm = DossierForm(instance=instance_dossier)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'dashboard/reviser_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2, 'dossier': instance_dossier})
```

Comment: You are passing `instance` to `DocumentFormSet` in the view "reviserdossier" in the `if request.method == 'GET':` block. You should pass a queryset to a formset not an instance

Comment: what's your forms.py ?

Comment: The form is populating now, I fixed the formset thing Iain pointed out to. But now, when I click on the submit button, it doesn't go back to /, and doesn't change anything, just refreshes the page. I edited the question with the latest code I made.

Comment: @MahrezBenHamad I added the forms.py for you

Comment: @KaissBouali did you find the solution? i have a similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370169/django-createview-doesnt-save-object-and-doesnt-give-error?noredirect=1#comment124397164_70370169 
could you please check it and let me know if you have any idea from your experience? thank you!