# Django CreateView doesn't save object and doesn't give error

Tags: python, django, forms, create-view

I'm working on a new project and I'm having difficulties adding new objects from the users page. It can be added from admin dashboard.
This is the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I have this view:

```
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    fields = ['title', 'image', 'description', 'price']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        #form.save() # tried this too and it didn't work
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

product_form.html:

```
{% extends "index/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Product</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content%}
```

I tried a couple of times and I didn't work. So I searched for solutions and tried the following:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.owner = self.request.user
instance.save()
return super().form_valid(instance)
```

and this

```
self.object.owner = self.request.user
self.object = form.save()
return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

within the form_valid(). Neither of them worked. So I can open the form and fill the fields. When I send it, the object is not saved but it doesn't give any error. It just reloads the form.

Comment: Please indent your class properly.

Comment: @bichanna done! thank you for the note :)

Comment: In your form_valid, try first save(commit=False), then add the owner field, and then finally call supers form_valid

Comment: @DavidJayBrady tried: form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form) and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after nearly one week of trying to fix the issue and not much help, I found a solution! `form_valid()` works fine the way it is, but the problem is in the form. Adding **`enctype`** fixes the problem:

> `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

The explanation I found for this is that without `enctype` the image data is not being passed correctly to the database. So it looks like the form is fine, but on the background it is not saving the image.